# Как исправить 401 при парсинге?

Tags: python, парсер, requests

```
import requests

url = 'https://proverkacheka.com/api/v1/check/get'

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0'
}

data = {
        'fn': fn,
        'fd': fd,
        'fp': fp,
        'n': 1,
        's': s,
        't': t,
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Получаю 200 при получении запроса, но в нем лежит {'code': 401, 'data': 'Не авторизован (не представился). Для доступа к запрашиваемому ресурсу требуется аутентификация.'}

Не знаю как адекватно парсить всё это дело, авторизация на сайте для получения данных не требуется. При этом форма на сайте отправляется с другого url (https://proverkacheka.com/). Но запрос поступает на url, который в коде.

Реализовал парсинг на селениуме, работает, но долго и костыльно.

Comment: Аутентифицироваться? Что значит с другого url? Как реализовал парсер без аутентификации?

Comment: понял проблему, когда делаю запрос с https://proverkacheka.com/ при помощи формы , в неё добавляется скрытое значение токена js скриптом

Answer (score 0):

понял проблему, когда делаю запрос с proverkacheka.com при помощи формы , в неё добавляется скрытое значение токена js скриптом